# Convertir un Queryset a un diccionario

Tags: python, django

Este es mi código en Django donde obtengo los colores que hay en una tabla:

```
>>> from charts.models import colores
>>> votos = colores.objects.values('color').distinct()
>>> print(votos)
<QuerySet [{'color': 'rojo'}, {'color': 'azul'}]>
```

Como pueden ver me retorna un queryset con formato de diccionario.

Sin embargo, necesito usar una caracteristica de diccionarios que no esta disponible (`dict.values()` para obtener los valores solamente).

¿Alguien sabe cómo almacenar ese queryset en un diccionario u obtener solo los valores del queryset (obtener rojo y **no** color : rojo)?

Comment: Qué has intentado? Ya probaste haciéndole el casting con `dict(votos)`?

Comment: si, lo probe y me arroja
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
y con list(votos) me lo convierte a una lista sin problemas... :(

Comment: Ahhh vale, no me había fijado que es una lista. Y si intentas esto: `list(map(lambda x: x['color'], votos))`?

Comment: >>> list(map(lambda x: x['color'], votos))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Cuando le haces `print(list)` ¿qué te sale?, justo antes de ejecutar el código que te dí. Deberías ver algo como esto: `<type 'list'>`

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener una list necesitas llamar a la función `values_list`, pasando como primer atributo el campo que deseas obtener y como segundo parámetro `flat=True`.

#### Ejemplo

```py
>>> from charts.models import colores
>>> votos = colores.objects.values_list('color', flat=True).distinct()
>>> print(votos)
<QuerySet ['rojo', 'azul']>
```

#### Documentación

- `values_list`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list